# How to pass a node as an argument in a Rundeck Job

Tags: rundeck

I have a main Rundeck job with an option **hostname(node)**.

And in this main Job I have a step **Job Reference**. and I would like to execute a command on the **hostname** passed as an argument.

Is that possible and how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use option passed into job as part of nodes filter. For example jobA reference JobB. JobB is Node-oriented and acept parameter hostname. So in Nodes section you can specify "Dispatch to nodes"=true (radio button and in filter set something like `name=${option.hostname}`

For example I am using next Node filters:
[image]

Comment: If you create an option in the job, passing ${option.hostname} is easy, but it's not clear to me either how to return the node value from the selected items in a filter instead. It doesn't seem to be the same thing.

Comment: This is the best answer I've found so far: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/612